# Disable ng-touch on on specific location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch, ui.bootstrap

I am using carousel from `ui.bootstrap` and for that i need to use ng-touch. When i inject my app with `ngTouch` it brakes some things, inputs in mobile can't be clicked.
How can i inject specific controller, i have tried to make two different modules but i have to load the module with ngTouch inside ng-app module and again that brakes things.

```
angular.module('appModule',['carouselModule'])
angular.module('carouselModule',['ngTouch','ui.bootstrap'])
```

Comment: You can't, angular modules don't work like this, you need to focus the question on how to remedy ngTouch side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the guide of @estus, i have found the solution.

```
directives.stopEvent=function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on(attr.stopEvent, function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    };
}
```

and in the html for example:

```
<div id="topbar" stop-event="touchend">...</div>
```